# Programmatically create a x509 certificate for iPhone without using OpenSSL

Tags: ios, ssl, x509certificate, x509

Is there a way to programmatically create a self-signed certificate in an app for iPhone just by using the Apple Security framework, ie. not having to mess with OpenSSL?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is not possible without openSSL or RSA libs, I have searched through some answers, and this one seems to be the best, even includes a connection to this question:
[iOS: How to create PKCS12 (P12) keystore from private key and x509certificate in application programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883342/ios-how-to-create-pkcs12-p12-keystore-from-private-key-and-x509certificate-in)