# iOS client certificate authentication in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, ssl

I am setting up an Apache server with client side authentication and accessing it from iOS with a client certificate.

I am taking some clues from [Swift iOS Client Certificate Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174052/swift-ios-client-certificate-authentication)

The code compiles with no errors, but returns KCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9829, and the Apachelog reads - peer did not return a certificate - No CAs know to server for verification.

The NSURLCredential given to the challenge reads NSURLCredential: 0x7fbad34d380: (null)

This code compiles with Xcode 7 for iOS 9.3.

Has anybody any suggestions to this error. My initial thought was that this was due to that the client certificate - p12 - is not properly presentet to the server.