# How to use openssl in swift private pod?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, openssl, cocoapods

I followed below link to use openssl to generate pkcs12 file in a ios swift project.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41856095/5059959

Now I want to create a private pod which requires openssl. How to can I do that?

I don't know how to do steps specified at above link

Could someone help me?